# How can I disable one Graphics card/GPU on my system? (Interchangeable graphics involved)

Tags: 12.04, ati, graphics, hybrid-graphics, vgaswitcheroo

The problem I have is this:

I have a DELL laptop with 2 GPUs, an Intel integrated and high performance of AMD Radeon HD a 6470m, but Ubuntu does not detect it. However, the two are active at the same time, which causes the equipment to overheat, and the to battery last less than 40 minutes.

I installed the Catalyst drivers but the system becomes unstable and heated even more. Please help me to solve this problem either by using the appropriate software, or by disabling either GPU in Ubuntu, As it is not possible to do so in the BIOS.

**System specs:**

```
Intel Core i5 CPU (with integrated GPU)
Intel HD 3000 1.5GB Integrated Graphics
AMD Radeon HD 6470m 512MB.
4GB RAM
```